# Oracle error log file

Tags: java, oracle, plsql, ora-06512, ora-29532

I'm running following block in Oracle (what does it do is not so important)

```
BEGIN
  SDO_RDF_INFERENCE.CREATE_RULES_INDEX(
    'my_index',
    SDO_RDF_Models('my_model'),
    SDO_RDF_Rulebases('RDFS'));
END;
```

and getting following error:

```
ORA-29532: Java call terminated by uncaught Java exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
ORA-06512: at "MDSYS.RDF_APIS_USER", line 7
ORA-06512: at "MDSYS.RDF_APIS_USER", line 9
ORA-06512: at "MDSYS.RDF_APIS", line 477
ORA-06512: at line 2
29532. 00000 -  "Java call terminated by uncaught Java exception: %s"
*Cause:    A Java exception or error was signaled and could not be
           resolved by the Java code.
*Action:   Modify Java code, if this behavior is not intended.
```

**Question:** how can I access Oracle error log or something to get full stack trace or any other information about exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually only DBA's have essential rights to view Oracle logs.
But,If you have enough rights:

```
select value from v$parameter t
where t.NAME='background_dump_dest'
```

This query will return the file path of the Oracle alert log and trace\dump files at Oracle Server machine. 
Alert log (Alert_"databasename".log) chronologically records messages and errors and containes pointers to trace\dump file assosiated whith them.

Also you can view alert_.log using Oracle Enterprise Managment Console following the "Alert Log Contents" link in the target database.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't answer the question on how to see more info in the log, but you may want to look at [this](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_29532_java_call_terminated_by_uncaught_java_exception_string.htm) for some possible reasons for the error.  Usually happens because you have not been granted permission to the Oracle object you are trying to access.

Answer (score 1):

Try execute this statement in your Oracle SQL session before calling the failing stored procedure:

```
dbms_java.set_output(32000);
```

It will cause the Oracle JVM to append a Java stacktrace to the DBMS output, which you can then examine in more detail.